# Python formating SRT files with SRT module

Tags: python, srt

It is impossible for me to make the composer method work with the `SRT` module. So I wrote this basic example and everything works mostly fine for my needs, but the compose doesn't work. Is there anything wrong with the way I'm using it?

```
from datetime import timedelta
import srt

td = timedelta(seconds=1)

a = srt.Subtitle(index=1, start=td, end=td, content='Word 1')
b = srt.Subtitle(index=2, start=td, end=td, content='Word 2')

c = [a, b]

print(srt.compose(c))

c = a.to_srt() + b.to_srt()

print("========")
print(c)

print("====")
d = list(srt.parse(c))
print(d)
```

Comment: Does it raise an error? What output did you expect and what do you get?

Comment: That's the weirdest thing: No errors. And debbuging I can se the I just got returned a blank string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was some mistake in the example code I was following. And for to solve this, I need to pass `reindex=False` to `srt.compose`.

Found this solution in the git-hub of the module.

https://github.com/cdown/srt/issues/62